# How can I select the minimum y-value for x-y pairs?

Tags: python, list

I have the following two arrays:

```
x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
y = [0.194, 0.183, 0.202, 0.169, 0.417]
```

The x-array features duplicates of the same value. If I were to plot these values as x,y pairs, the graph would look like columns of dots.

I want to make a script that chooses the lowest y-value for a given x-value, joins that y-value with its associated x-value, and then plots that pair. The other y-values for each value of x are ignored.

I've tried using nested for loops, slicing, if/else statements, etc., but I can't make anything work. The most common result I get is the lowest y-value of the entire array joined with all the x-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As demonstrated by the other answers on this page, it's possible to solve this using only Python's built-in libraries, albeit verbosely.

However, if you'll be doing this sort of thing often -- or with large datasets -- it may be worth learning to use the `pandas` package, which is loaded with convenient tools for common data manipulation tasks like this.

Once your data is loaded into a `DataFrame`, your answer can be computed in one line:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
y = [0.194, 0.183, 0.202, 0.169, 0.417]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
mins = df.groupby('x')['y'].min()

print(mins.index.tolist())
print(mins.values.tolist())
```

```
[10, 20]
[0.183, 0.169]
```

Or here's another option:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
y = [0.194, 0.183, 0.202, 0.169, 0.417]
z = [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})
filtered = df.sort_values(['x', 'y']).drop_duplicates('x')
print(filtered)
```

```
    x      y  z
1  10  0.183  2
3  20  0.169  1
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the solution I was looking for. If I may, I have one more question. Suppose I have another array, call it z, with integer values that may or may not be repeated. This array serves as an identifier for each of the y-values, so that the x-y pairs can be labeled in the plot. How would I use pd.groupby to include the z array? After adding my z array to the dataframe, I've tried inserting z into the groupby statement in various ways. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Assuming you've loaded your DataFrame with all three columns (x,y,z), then instead of `groupby`, you can also use `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates` as follows: `df.sort_values(['x', 'y']).drop_duplicates('x')`

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
y = [0.194, 0.183, 0.202, 0.169, 0.417]
pairs = [(x, min(map(itemgetter(1), y))) for x, y in groupby(zip(x, y), itemgetter(0))]
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what the code does instead of just dumping code

Answer (score 1):

In linear time, O(n), I think.

```
x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
y = [0.194, 0.183, 0.202, 0.169, 0.417]

lowestDict = dict()
for i in range(len(x)):
  currentY = lowestDict.get(x[i], None)
  if currentY is None or y[i] < currentY:
    lowestDict[x[i]] = y[i]

pairs = list(d.items())
print(pairs)
```

Comment: It would help if you actually explained what your solution does instead of just dumping your code.

Comment: Also, don't iterate using `for i in range(len(x))`. Do `for i, x_elem in enumerate(x)`. Better yet, since you want to iterate over `x` and `y` simultaneously, do `for x_elem, y_elem in zip(x, y)`

Comment: Also also, `[(k, v) for k, v in lowestDict.items()]` -> `list(lowestDict.items())`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `dict` with `float('inf')` on `x`, then use `zip`, and save `min` value of `y` for each `key`. At the end, convert `dict` to `list` of `tuple`s.

```
x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 20]
y = [0.194, 0.183, 0.202, 0.169, 0.417]

# create a 'dict' and use values of 'x' as 'key'
dct = {i: float('inf') for i in set(x)}

# find min value for each 'key' base each pair in (x, y)
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    dct[i] = min(dct[i], j)

# convert 'dct' to 'list' of 'tuple's
res = list(dct.items())
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[(10, 0.183), (20, 0.169)]
```

Comment: You could also do `dct = collections.defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))` to avoid one iteration over `x`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, thanks, Yes, we can write that, but I prefer a readable solution.